# jqGrid filterToolbar only works with some columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, filter, jqgrid

When I try searching for the string `Test` in the column "Erstellt Von", I get no results. There's no error in the console either.

[image]

[image]

This is the codepart I used:

```
var colUserTemplate = {
    width: 160, align: 'left',
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

In another column, the filtering works perfectly fine:

[image]

Here's how grids are loaded and the `filterToolbar`:

```
function loadGrid(listname, query, divname, colnames, colmdodel, showFilter, showExcelExport) {

    $("#" + divname).jqGrid({
        datatype: function () { loadGridData(listname, query, divname); },
        colNames: colnames,
        colModel: colmdodel,
        height: "100%",
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 9999,
        gridComplete: function () {
            $("#" + divname + "no").html("&nbsp;[" + $("#" + divname).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') + "]");
            $("#" + divname).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'local' });
        },
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
            onDoubleClickGrid(rowid, iRow, iCol, e, divname, listname);
        }
    });

    if (showFilter) {
        $("#" + divname).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
            autosearch: true,
            stringResult: false,
            searchOnEnter: true,
            defaultSearch: "cn",
        });
    }
}
```

I tried using

```
if (showFilter) {
    $("#" + divname).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        autosearch: true,
        stringResult: true,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        defaultSearch: "cn", ignoreCase: true
    });
}
```

but it didn't change anything.

If you want to have a look, [here's the full code.](https://pastebin.com/qVQMXTJC)

Been trying to fix this issue for hours, so any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

When writing this:

```
var thegrid = $("#" + divname)[0];
console.log("data.d.results: " + data.d.results);
thegrid.addJSONData(data.d.results); //Binding data to the grid
console.log("thegrid:" + thegrid.innerHTML);
```

I get the following result:
[image]

Here's the expanded object:

[image]

Comment: The reason for this is that you use a custom formatter. This formatter return your own value, while the local searching is performed on the local data, which is stored in data array. With other words - grid perform search not on the displayed values in the grid, but on these stored into the data array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So what can I do about this?

Comment: To put these value first into the response. You use datatype as function, so put the formated values here.

Comment: What exactly do I have to write to put the formated values into the datatype function? Can you write an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a function to load the data:

```
function loadGridData(listname, query, divname) {

$.ajax({
    url: "/tools/AKG/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/Items?" + query,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var thegrid = $("#" + divname)[0];
        thegrid.addJSONData(data.d.results); //Binding data to the grid
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error:" + JSON.stringify(xhr));
        $('#' + divname + 'records').html(" [0]");
    }
});
}
```

In the success function data.d.results contain your grid data. Before to put this data in addJSONData loop over that column and change its value or better do it at server if possible

Comment: I know that I can print out the grid data using `console.log("thegrid:" + thegrid.innerHTML);`, but I don't understand what you mean with "loop over that column and change its value"

Comment: data.d.results is object array (better object) which contain the data for the grid. Usually this object has rows, that are a  grid rows. Every row contain a set of name : value pair that correspond to a grid cell. If you do console.log(data.d.results) before addJSONData you will see the source that will be put into the grid. So befor to put this into the grid you can change here the values.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make anything out of this

Comment: Can you please do a console.log( data.d.results ) just before thegrid.addJSONData in function loadGridData and post me a partial or demo result?

Comment: `console.log( data.d.results )` leads to `[object Object],[object Object]`, but I edited the post. (see above)

Comment: I need that [object Object],[object Object] - can you please expand that object in order to see the result

Comment: Edited post with expanded object

Comment: Fixed it by using `Author.Title` and adapting the custom formatter

I still gave you the bounty for trying to help :)

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear that you have solved the problem.